# Calculating confidence intervals of grouped binary data with dplyr

Tags: r, binary, dplyr, confidence-interval

I am fairly new to R as well as to analysing binary data, and am currently attempting to assess whether the anxiety rates of participants are associated with their exposure to a risk factor. To do this I initially plan to work out the proportion of participants in each exposure group that were diagnosed with anxiety with 95% confidence intervals, and plot these. However my confidence interval calculation is not correct, and I can't work out why. A simplified version of my dataset is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

anxietytable <- tibble(
  id = c(1:709),
  exposure = c(rep("mild", 29), rep("severe", 29), rep("unexposed", 3), rep("mild", 337), rep("severe", 203), rep("unexposed", 108)),
  case_anxiety = as.logical(c(rep("TRUE", 61), rep("FALSE", 648)))
  )
```

The calculation to calculate the proportions and confidence intervals is as follows:

```
anxiety_rates <- anxietytable %>%
  group_by(exposure) %>%
  summarise(anxiety_rate= mean(case_anxiety),
            anxiety_uci= anxiety_rate+(1.96*sd(case_anxiety)/sqrt(sum(case_anxiety))),
            anxiety_lci= anxiety_rate-(1.96*sd(case_anxiety)/sqrt(sum(case_anxiety))))
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
   exposure anxiety_rate anxiety_uci  anxiety_lci
      <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
1      mild   0.07923497   0.1776778 -0.019207848
2    severe   0.12500000   0.2456297  0.004370339
3 unexposed   0.02702703   0.2113630 -0.157308955
```

I was somewhat suspicious of the error bars when I plotted the graph, so I tested it manually with binom.test using the overall and TRUE counts for the "mild" exposure group (prop.test also returns similar values, as do several online tools):

```
 binom.test(29,366)
```

returns:

```
data:  29 and 366
number of successes = 29, number of trials = 366, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05370521 0.11181316
sample estimates:
probability of success 
            0.07923497
```

Therefore my proportion calculation seems correct but my confidence intervals are not. I'm assuming this is most likely because I've made an error in the code or used a function inappropriately rather than due to a statistical misunderstanding (though if not I'd be happy to ask in CrossValidated instead), but I've been through it quite a few times and altered the bracketing etc. and can't find out why it is not giving the value I'm expecting.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to restructure my code so that the confidence interval is calculated correctly?

Comment: Your code assumes a normal distribution for your binomial error...

Comment: I would recomend reading about binomian CI, for example this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)